# How to Train End to End model with Part RNN and Part Graph Neural Network?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on a project in which I need to use RNNs in part of a neural network. Essentially the RNN would take in a text of variable length and output a feature representation. This feature representation would then be clubbed with some more feature vectors and fed to a different graph neural network. Some loss would be calculated on the output of the graph neural network and this loss would be backpropagated across the entire network including the RNN and be used to train the entire end to end network.

However, I am not able to wrap my head around how I can use the RNN as a part of another different non-sequential model. I use PyTorch for most of my work.

Can anyone suggest any way in which I may address this problem. Or refer to any material which might be useful.

Thanks